# Scrape text in descending order and verify isSelected method

Tags: java, selenium

URL - https://www.etmoney.com/mutual-funds/filter/long-term-funds-return

Task 1: Get all the returns and verify if it is sorted in descending order

```java
List<WebElement> returns = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[@class='mfFund-nav-row even']//td[11]"));
for(int ii=0; i<returns.size(); i++) {
    String returnDesc = returns.get(i).getText();
    System.out.println(returnDesc);
}
```

The above code only scrapes data alternately i.e there are 12 elements but only 7-8 are selected .

Task 2: Verify if “Long-Term Historic Returns” is selected in the Returns section.

```java
WebElement historicReturn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[normalize-space()='Long-Term Historic Returns']"));
Assert.assertTrue(historicReturn.isSelected());
```

Not able to verify the above code as it returns false every time even if the element is selected.

Answer (score 0):

For task 1
You can use below code using java8
First get the list of "Scheme name" from the table, collect the visible values into a list.
Now Create two Lists with text for the elements and sort one of them in descending order, now compare the list using equals ,if the order is descending then it should print true to console

```
 //get the Table elements
      List<WebElement> returns = driver.findElements(
              By.xpath("//tr[@class='mfFund-nav-row']//td[1]//a")).stream()
          .filter(WebElement::isDisplayed).collect(Collectors.toList());
      //Store text in a Descending order in list
      List<String> decsSorted = returns.stream().map(WebElement::getText)
          .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList());
      //Store text in a actual order in list
      List<String> actualList = returns.stream().map(WebElement::getText)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
      //compare and print
      System.out.println(actualList.equals(decsSorted));
```

For Task 2 , way you can find if element is checked is like below
Find child div element like below, if the child div element class changes to "radiobox active" then it means its checked , if its checked then you will get the element otherwise it will throw below NoSuchElementException

```
  try {
             driver.findElement(
                     By.xpath("//label[normalize-space()='Long-Term Historic Returns']"))
                 .findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class= \"radiobox active\"]"));
             System.out.println(true);
          } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
             System.out.println(false);
          }
```